# How to add icon to spinner (where find the default value)

Tags: android, android-spinner

how i add icon to spinner **by xml** where find the default value (not in the the list) ??

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.28"
            android:prompt="@string/language_prompt"
            android:textSize="12sp"   <!-- icon insten of text -->

             />
```

i try  `android:Background="@drawable/world_language_icon"` but doesn't work.

i dont find src or set drawable .

[I dont find here (in google)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

[i need xml and not java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633333/android-layout-controls-side-by-side)[also here i find in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609231/how-is-it-possible-to-create-a-spinner-with-images-instead-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should probably try proof reading your question before posting, and make sure you know exactly what you want to know.

```
how i add icon to spinner by xml
```

The icon is **not** added to the spinner itself, as what you use to populate the Spinner is an adapter. In order to add an icon to your Spinner items, you would need to create a custom adapter to set to the Spinner, and use a custom layout for  the List Items.

```
where find the defult value (not in the the list) ??
```

That, I'm not sure what you are asking for. If your question is how to **set** a default item/value for the Spinner, it's not possible. The default item set will **always** be the first item on the List you populate the Spinner with. You can of course automatically select a different Spinner item in code, but even then you'll notice that the first item was selected **before** your other actions.